# Getting minify (css/js compression) to work on dedicated server

Tags: css, webserver, gzip, minify

I am using minify http://code.google.com/p/minify/
or https://github.com/mrclay/minify/

I have no trouble getting min to work on my local environment, and localhost:8888/min/f=min/quick-test.css works fine.

I am trying to get this working on the 'dev' environment of my server... so I set up a subdomain at dev.example.com, and created a new web root at /dev_html/ instead of /public_html/. This all seems to be working though, because when I run echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], it works as expected. So I don't think the subdomain has anything to do with why this isn't working.

I am testing with an untouched version of min on my server, directly in my subdomain's document root, but when I test dev.mydomain.com/min/f=min/quick-test.css, I receive an Internal Server Error on the request.

Thanks for any help,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the groups feature?

I hadn't actually tried using the f parameter but like you having just tried it it only works locally for me. Strange! The groups work fine though.

Try a group instead by amending /min/groupsConfig.php.

```
'css' => array('../css/stye_1.css', '../css/style_2.css'),
```

The paths are relative to the min directory.

Access it through the browser using the g parameter:

```
/min/g=css
```

Comment: I like the group feature and that's what I've been using locally. I use that an append file extension in PHP, because it seems to load faster and I think it's odd to call CSS/js in browser without extension. Not sure why the group default is no extension.

Anyways, what I posted is included in every min download, to use as a test CSS file to see if it is working. But since I'm getting a server error on that, something's not working correctly.

Btw I had same problem when using groups, that's why I switched to the test file.